# Extract matrix component from $Mx⋅Mx$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this expression of dot product where M is a matrix and x is a vector:
$$Mx⋅Mx$$

Can I simplify this by extracting the matrix component somehow?

Assuming two cases where M is an orthogonal matrix or a skew symmetric matrix.

Comment: You mean that you want to expand the sums?

Comment: I believe the expression you ask about is $x^T M^T M x$.  If you were able to evaluate this expression for arbitrary values of vector $x$, it would give you some information about $M^T M$, but not enough to reconstruct $M$ by itself.

Comment: @hardmath Thanks! But what if M is a skew symmetric matrix. Or a rotation matrix. Could we simplify this further?

Comment: @Vincent No I wasn't thinking of expanding the sums.

Comment: Yes, if you have some information about $M$, that can be used to simplify the expression.  E.g. if $M$ is a rotation matrix (more generally, an orthogonal matrix), then $M^T M = I$ and the expression simplifies to $x^T x$, the length of $x$ squared.

Comment: @hardmath Thanks! The math makes sense to me that $M^TM$ for orthogonal matrix would be equal to 1. But conceptually I don't quite get why the matrix component in the expression  $Mx⋅Mx$ doesn't matter if it's orthogonal. Also what about a skew symmetric matrix?

Comment: The short explanation is that multiplication of a vector by an orthogonal matrix preserves the length of that vector.  So you wind up with $x\cdot x$ being the same as $(Mx)\cdot(Mx)$, provided of course that $M$ is known to be an orthogonal matrix.

Comment: @hardmath Oh this makes sense thank you! I updated my question. Could you provide this as an answer? You wrote previously that for skew symmetric matrix $M^T = -M$ so the expression simplifies to $-||M⋅x||^2$(?). But could you explain this in more steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression $Mx \cdot Mx$, where $M$ is a matrix and $x$ a compatible vector, can always be rewritten:

$$ x^T M^T Mx = ||Mx||^2 $$

In other words, this is the (Euclidean) length of $Mx$ squared.

In the case that $M$ is an *orthogonal matrix*, this simplifies to $x^T x = ||x||^2$ because by definition $M^T M = I$.

The case when $M$ is *skew symmetric* is less amenable to simplification.  By definition $M^T = -M$ for skew symmetry, so in that case:

$$ x^T M^T Mx = -x^T M^2 x $$

However this by itself appears not useful without further information about $M^2$.